# Calculate Standard Deviation in TensorflowJS?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm writing my first TFJS demo app. I have a well trained cats/dogs binary classifier that I've converted using the converter. I can load the model and pass images from an iphone or android camera for classification. Unfortunately, the results are terrible. My model was trained using a keras ImageDataGenerator with samplewise_center and samplewise_std_normalization both set to true. I'm now pretty sure I need to do the same normalization in my app.

I see tf.math.reduce_mean() and reduce_std() in the full API. In the JS API I see ts.mean() but no ts.std(). Do I need to calculate std from scratch?

Answer (score 5):

There is not yet an operator to compute the standard deviation in the js api. It can either be computed from scratch or use `tf.moments` to get the variance and then compute the standard deviation usinng the square root.

```
const a = tf.tensor1d([1, 2, 3]);

tf.moments(a).variance.print()
tf.moments(a).variance.sqrt().print()
```